# Register custom domain locally without using host file

Tags: dns, localhost

I have installed Topaz SignWeb which installs an agent to capture the signature. I am trying to understand where the internal server in my machine. I found the below in Chrome DevTool,

[image]

So the domain tablet.sigwebtablet.com points to my localhost. Then I open C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file but I couldn't find this entry. I am curious now how can we register a domain locally without using host file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran an online domain to IP convertor and found out that tablet.sigwebtablet.com points to 127.0.0.1 (local IP). I have also found out that they use http.sys for URL reservation/registration. I have found out this using,

1. netsh http show urlacl (which shows the reserved urls)
2. netsh http show servicestate (which shows a list of Server Session with the URL)